# Check if DB Exists in a Trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have an SQL Trigger that is dependent on a separate database in the same server, but the issue arises when one wants to use the database independently, in which case the second database will usually not be migrated. Meaning that, if a query were to be executed that would activate the Trigger, it will fail due to requiring that second database.

I attempted to circumvent the issue by covering the entire trigger with a script that checks if the database exists, but even when I do include it, it will basically check the entire trigger and will fail anyway. Below is what happened when I inserted a record in an SQL server without the 2nd database.

```
Msg 2702, Level 16, State 2, Procedure tChange2ndDB, Line 22 [Batch Start Line 0]
Database '2ndDB' does not exist.
```

Here's what my current (basic) code looks like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tChange2ndDB] 
   ON  [dbo].[crelign] 
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE ('[' + name + ']' = '[2ndDB]' OR name = '[2ndDB]')))
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @insCount INT
        DECLARE @delCount INT
        DECLARE @Code VARCHAR(5)
        DECLARE @CodeUpd VARCHAR(5)
        DECLARE @Description VARCHAR(50)

        SET @insCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INSERTED)
        SET @delCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DELETED)

        ;IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE ('[' + name + ']' = '[2ndDB]' OR name = '[2ndDB]')))
            ALTER TABLE [2ndDB].[dbo].Field DISABLE TRIGGER [tChange1stDB];

        -- * Other code here * --

        ;IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE ('[' + name + ']' = '[2ndDB]' OR name = '[2ndDB]')))
            ALTER TABLE [2ndDB].[dbo].Field ENABLE TRIGGER [tChange1stDB];

    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        -- * Error Handling --
        DECLARE @ErrMsg NVARCHAR(MAX), @ErrorSeverity INT, @ErrorState INT;

        SELECT @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

        SET @ErrMsg = (SELECT 'TR : tChange2ndDB Line : ' + RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ERROR_LINE())) + ' - ' + ERROR_MESSAGE());

        RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
    END CATCH
END
END
GO
```

What is the best solution to overcome this issue?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: To which database did you add the Trigger?

Comment: This sort of trigger appears on both the primary database (1stDB) and secondary database (2ndDB), for purpose of syncing specific tables in the 2ndDB that have a matching table in the 1stDB.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding an Else and then use RETURN 0 or '' to dont do your code.

Comment: No, that does not work. 

Using "Return 0", I got this message (it cannot be updated): 
Msg 178, Level 15, State 1, Procedure tChange2ndDB, Line 43 [Batch Start Line 2]
A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.

Also, I used "PRINT ''", in which case I will get this when I insert a record: 
Msg 2702, Level 16, State 2, Procedure tChange2ndDB, Line 21 [Batch Start Line 0]
Database '2ndDB' does not exist.